# update triggers in sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sqlplus

I want to implement a trigger when certain row is updated.

There is an attribute called pno in the offer table.

```
create table logFile
(
    pno int primary key, 
    user_name varchar(100), 
    date_chan date, 
    old_Price int, 
    new_Price int
);

create or replace trigger update_price_property 
   AFTER UPDATE OF price ON offer 
   IF pno = 80 // this won't work, how can I add this condition?
   BEGIN
     insert into logFile values (:old.pno, user, sysdate, :old.price, :new.price);
   END;
/
```

Comment: I got a compilation error by doing that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can phrase this just as an `insert`:

```
BEGIN
    insert into logFile 
        select :old.pno, user, sysdate, :old.price, :new.price
        from dual
        where :old.pno = 80;  -- or is this :new.pno?
END;
```

Of course, you can also use an `if` condition.